# create OS back up

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, dell, 9.04

hello

I have ubuntu 9 that I take with my Dell laptop! this CD contain a program that I can create a copy of all ubuntu files & programs into a CD and Run it from CD(live) or Intslall it(with all programs)
new I installed ubuntu 10 that I downloaded from ubuntu website, I installed dozens of programs from apache to games,from browser to code editor), Now I want to create back up of my ubuntu that I able to run it from CD or installed it (and installed ubuntu include my prgrams)

Now I want to now Is there any program for my purpose?
Note: I could not find any dell related program,If there is any,it will be better to use it:)

Comment: You may find your answer in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Answer (score 5):

[Remastersys](http://geekconnection.org/remastersys/) is the solution. You can make backup with all data of your home folder.

Comment: Yes this sounds like the better solution. Guess I have to try it myself too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/ with this you can backup your installed programs to cd (no live version).
For your files you might want to take a look at Deja Dup ( https://launchpad.net/deja-dup ) it will be the new standard backup tool in ubuntu 11.10

Comment: AptonCD only works when your package is saved in /var/apt/cache folder. If you clean you packages, then AptonCD won't work

Comment: @crucifiedsoul: it can download them...

Comment: @Roland: Then it's not backing up.

Comment: @cruciiedsoul: yes it is.